# Scroll should appear for entire table with fixed table header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with scroll bar and it applies for tbody. It is working fine. 
what i need is I need the scroll applicable for the entire table with the table header should be fixed in the position.[image].

I have the working sample. Please check the [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ykjxzL3d/9/)

I want the table ui should look like with table header fixed in the position while scrolling.[image]

Comment: I don't understand what is missing.

Comment: whats missing? i dont get it can you provide more information?

Comment: i need the vertical scrollbar for the entire table and `thead` should be fixed in the position. see now the scrollbar starts from `tbody`.

Comment: Hmm, if I understand correctly, aren't the two requirements contradictory to eachother? What you have now, is that the table header is fixed and only the table body scrolls, hence the scrollbar is shown only on the body. The desired visual has the header included in the scrolling, but it still has to be fixed. Easiest solution I see is not using a thead and faking it with a fixed div or using two different tables, one with only a thead and one with only a tbody. Then again, the desired functionality matches your current visual better imho, since only the body has to scroll.

Comment: Tbh I would very much prefer the behaviour you want to replace.

Comment: @connexo what kinda behaviour i want to replace.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hacked method for what you have asked. Please verify if it this is the output you were expecting.

```css
.container {
   overflow: auto;
   height: 100px;
}
.fixed_header{
   width: 100%;
   table-layout: fixed;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   position: relative;
}

.fixed_header tbody{
   display:block;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 30px; //Height of the header
}

.fixed_header thead tr {
   display: block;
}

.fixed_header thead {
   background: black;
   color:#fff;
   position: absolute; //To fix the header on the top of the table
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
}

.fixed_header th, .fixed_header td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<table class="fixed_header">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 2-0</td>
      <td>row 2-1</td>
      <td>row 2-2</td>
      <td>row 2-3</td>
      <td>row 2-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 3-0</td>
      <td>row 3-1</td>
      <td>row 3-2</td>
      <td>row 3-3</td>
      <td>row 3-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 4-0</td>
      <td>row 4-1</td>
      <td>row 4-2</td>
      <td>row 4-3</td>
      <td>row 4-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 5-0</td>
      <td>row 5-1</td>
      <td>row 5-2</td>
      <td>row 5-3</td>
      <td>row 5-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 6-0</td>
      <td>row 6-1</td>
      <td>row 6-2</td>
      <td>row 6-3</td>
      <td>row 6-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.